# NodeJs Array.join with text on each part of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I want to make something that console logs

```
Name1 Is Ready
Name2 Is Ready
Name3 Is ready
```

and each name is in an array(so Something like this)

```js
let array = []

array.push("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
```

I can't seem to get it to work as I want since when I try to console log it with

```js
console.log(array.join("\n") + "is Ready")
```

I get

```
Name1
Name2
Name3is ready
```

Is there any way to make it console log like

```
Name1 Is Ready
Name2 Is Ready
Name3 Is ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]

array.forEach(node => {
  console.log(node + " is Ready!")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the array to achieve what you're looking for

like this

```js
array.forEach(name => {
    console.log(name + "is Ready")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of elements all with the same prefix you can create an array, and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements into a string.

```js
const arr = new Array(3)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => `Name${i + 1}`);

const str = arr.map(el => `${el} is ready`).join('\n');

console.log(str);
```